# Problem with PostgreSQL json object (PGobject) to logstash - type cast problem

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am trying to index data from a PostgreSQL database to elastic search using logstash. I have a column in the database which is of type JSON. When I run logstash, I get an error called "Missing Converter handling". I do understand that is java/logstash doesn't recognize the JSON type column.

I can typecast the column to "col_name::TEXT" which works fine. However, I need that column as JSON in an elastic search index. Is there any workaround?

Note: Keys in the JSON object is not fixed, it varies.

```
Logstash postgres query example:

input {
    jdbc {
        # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, bot
        jdbc_connection_string => "***"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "***"
        jdbc_password => "***"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "<ja_file_path>"
        # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, json_col_4 from my_db;"
    }
}
filter{
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

Need JSON object from PostgreSQL to elastic search.

Comment: Thanks, Mark for editing.

Comment: Use the [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) plugin, which will parse a text field as json. In your case, it would look like this: `json {
    source => "json_col_4"
  }`

Comment: @baudsp  i'm not bothering you, but I wonder is this working solution? when column type is geometry